# Functions in the induced space compactly supported in $PN^-$ modulo $P$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, reductive-groups

Let $P_0$ be a minimal parabolic subgroup of a connected, reductive group $G$ over a $p$-adic field $k$.  Let $P$ be a parabolic subgroup containing $P_0$ with Levi decomposition $P = MN$.  Let $N^-$ be a group such that $P^- = MN^-$ is opposite to $P$.

Let $\pi$ be a smooth, irreducible representation of $M$, and consider a function $f$ in the space of the induced representation $\sigma = \operatorname{Ind}_{P}^G \pi $.  Then $f$ is locally constant, and there is a compact set $Z$ such that if $f(x) \neq 0$, then $px \in Z$ for some $p \in P$, i.e. $f$ is compactly supported modulo $P$.

I have seen in a few talks and papers the practice of fixing a function $f \in \sigma$ which vanishes outside of the open set $PN^-$.  I was wondering a couple of things:

1 .  Are are there "many" such functions?  How do we know that they exist at all?

2 .  If $f$ vanishes outside $PN^-$, since $N^-$ is the union of its open compact subgroups, is it possible to find a compact open subgroup $N_0$ of $N^-$ such that if $f(x) \neq 0$, then $px \in N_0$ for some $p \in P$?

Question 2 seems like a natural thing to expect, but I could not prove it.  I thought I might take the image in $P \backslash G$ of the support of $f$, which is compact, and cover it by the images of the open compact subgroups $N_0$.  The problem is that I don't think the images of $N_0$ are open in $P \backslash G$, since they are not open in $G$.

Comment: Surely you don't mean $P^- = P N^-$, but $P^- = M N^-$?

Comment: Sorry, can you explain more on why $PN^-$ being a direct product implies (1)?  (2) makes sense.

Comment: This was extremely helpful, thank you very much

Comment: I have moved my comments to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer moved from the comments.

1. They exist because $P \times N^- \to G$ is an open embedding (even on the level of varieties).  This implies that, for $f \in \mathrm C^\infty_{\mathrm c}(N^−; \sigma)$, the function $p n^− \mapsto \pi(p)f(n^−)$ has image in the appropriate function space (for $n^− \in N^−$, the image of $f$ is constant on $\operatorname{stab}_P(f(n^−))N^−_0$, where $N^−_0$ is an open subgroup of $N^−$ such that $f$ is constant on $n^− N^−_0$).
2. Not $N_0$ (which I think it would be better to call $N^−_0$, as above) but $P N_0$ is open, because of (1), so the image of $N_0$ in $P\backslash G$ is open.